# execute 'ls' command as a different User within python script

Tags: python, callback

Folks,
Here's what I am trying to do: my script will be running as root, I wish to execute various commands (say ls, rm, touch etc) as different users.

The problem I have is that using `preexec_fn=os.setuid(userid))` is setting the userid of the parent process as well. Suggestions please? Is `preexec_fn` the wrong way to achieve this? A further note is that this needs to be in the twisted way (which I might not be). Is `getProcessOutputAndValue` the way to go? If so, how to do something like this?

```
print 'uid is %s' % os.getuid()
cmdstr = ['ls']
process = subprocess.Popen(cmdstr,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, preexec_fn=os.setuid(10033))
print 'uid of parent after child startup is %s' % os.getuid()
process.wait()
print 'uid of parent after child finished is %s' % os.getuid()
```

output:

```
uid is 0
uid of parent after child startup is 10033
uid of parent after child finished is 10033
```

Comment: why are you not using `os.listdir (for ls)`, `os.utime` (touch), `shutil (rm) or os.remove )` ?

Comment: kurumi, 'coz I need to execute those commands as the supplied user (on a NFS directory, actually). Is there a way to have os.listdir execute as a given user/userid?

Comment: you mean to say you want to run the script as root, but run the commands as a user? I thought usually, you use sudo , or su  to do that? You sudo to the user, and then execute the Python script.

Comment: @kurumi, that's exactly what I mean. I am running the script as root and I need to run the ls/rm commands as another user (since the operation will happen on an NFS file, and I actually want to verify permissions by executing ls/rm commands as that user/userid).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that you are accidentally calling the preexec_fn when you're only trying to pass a callback to Popen.

Try this instead:

```
def my_preexec_fn():
    os.setuid(10033)
process = subprocess.Popen(cmdstr,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, preexec_fn=my_preexec_fn)
```

Comment: Yikes, that was a simple fix. Thanks. I suppose it's a bit of python artifact to not catch the fact that preexec_fn is being NOT set to a callable object -- the way I wrote it, it would get set to return value of os.setuid(10033) which is 'NoneType'!

Comment: helpmelearn, you marked rlibby's answer as *the* answer, but you didn't upvote it too (and since it's useful, you should :)

Comment: @TZ: I had attempted to do that, but then I did not have that capability then (I was too new to the site). :)

Answer (score 1):

rlibby's answer is correct and adequate as-is, however I'd like to add the following option for creation of the callback:

```
import functools as ft
my_preexec_fn= ft.partial(os.setuid, 10033)
```

Comment: @TZ: I am not aware what partial does here. And the documentation doesn't quite explain it either (IMO). Could you please elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: @helpmelearn: Assume there's a function `callable` taking two arguments: arg1, arg2. `partial= functools.partial(callable, arg1)` assigns a “partial” callable needing only arg2. Think: `operator.mul` is the multiplication operator taking two arguments. `mult3= functools.partial(operator.mul, 3)` assigns to `mult3` a callable which takes one argument and returns its argument multiplied by 3.